# Change activity without having to re-login asmack

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I have activity A which has a ListView populated by usernames via the Roster()... On item click it takes you to activity B which is supposed to allow you to send a message to the selected user. Problem is that both activities need XMPPConnection objects which are initialized in my app by logging in... And therefore both activities do separate logins which is super slow. Can someone show me a more efficient way way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need place your login info(ticket or sessionId) into a singleton object, for example, you can add an LoginClient, here you can store the login info and do the http request  staff.

cause it is a singleton with sync methods, your two activity will keep the instance of it and check the session whether it is not valid, then call the login logic again and replace the out-of-date login info again once you got the response.

Comment: Can you please show me a snippet of code...Cause I don't see a LoginClient class